# AWS Cognito , logins method of AWSIdentityProviderManager protocol is not getting called for iOS

Tags: ios, facebook, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

We are trying to use AWS Cognito for Facebook login, 
However when integrating with the code as per AWS documentation like below

```
class FacebookProvider: NSObject, AWSIdentityProviderManager {

    func logins() -> AWSTask<NSDictionary> {
                if let token = AccessToken.current?.authenticationToken {
                    return AWSTask(result: [AWSIdentityProviderFacebook:token])
                }
                return AWSTask(error:NSError(domain: "Facebook Login", code: -1 , userInfo: ["Facebook" : "No current Facebook access token"]))
            }
        }
```

This code we have written in `AppDelegate.swift` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method

```
FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

     let obj = FacebookProvider()

    let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType:.USEast1, identityPoolId:"somepoolid",identityProviderManager: obj)

    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region:.USEast1, credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider)

AWSServiceManager.default().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
```

Here we see that the logins method is not getting called.

Since the logins method is not getting called we are not able to pass facebook authentication token to amazon cognito.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hi, Did you set your IdentityProviderManager delegate?

Comment: Delegate is not set , please let me know how to set it

Comment: Hi, did you solve the issue?